# Unable to make prediction on google automl

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-automl-nl

I trained a model and would like to predict the score of a new image.

Now I execute the following function but it returns an error:

`google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'automl.models.predict' denied on resource 'projects/project_id/locations/us-central1/models/model_id' (or it may not exist).`

I am not sure if it is due to incorrect location, i.e. us-central1? What is the gcloud command to check?

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

```
def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):

    prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()
    name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
    payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
    return request  # waits till request is returned
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission error messages are usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly; Therefore, it is required to verify that the service account you are using has the required [roles assigned](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart#add_permissions_for_the_automl_vision_service_account), as well as [provide the credentials to your application](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) by using environment variables or explicitly point to your service account file in code. Keep in mind that when you set an environment variable value in a session, it is reset every time the session is dropped.

Additionally, **AutoML Vision** currently requires the location **us-central1**, as mentioned in the [API Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial#configure_your_project_environment). Based on this, you should be fine on this aspect; However, you can take a look on the [projects.locations](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations/get) REST methods in case you want to get additional information about this config.

You can use the following official documentation example to **Pass the path to the service account key in code**, as well as the [QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart) guide, to know more about the required configuration to begin using AutoML Vision service.

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;

// Imports the Google Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function auth_cloud_explicit($projectId, $serviceAccountPath)
{
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    $config = [
        'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ];
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}
```